# How to send a map between flutter widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to send a map to another screen. The constructor of the 2nd screen is below.

```
class Sell extends StatefulWidget {
  Map<String, int> cart = {};

  Sell({@required cart}); 
  @override
  _SellState createState() => _SellState();
}
```

This is the Page, calls the constructor of the second screen but I cant send a parameter like this.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Map<String, int> cart = {};

           \\\
 List pages = [
    Sell(cart: cart,), //this is the error <--Only static members can be accessed in initializers.dart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)


           \\\

}
  ];
```

Here is the source code of the first page

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentPage = 0;
  Map<String, int> cart = {};

  List pages = [
    Sell(cart: cart,),
    Cart(),
    Report(),
    Dashboard(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(

        ),

        body: Center(
          child: pages.elementAt(currentPage),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: FancyBottomNavigation(
          tabs: [
            TabData(iconData: Icons.attach_money, title: "Sell"),
            TabData(iconData: Icons.shopping_cart, title: "Basket"),
            TabData(iconData: Icons.assessment, title: "Reports"),
            TabData(iconData: Icons.dashboard, title: "Dashboard"),

          ],
          onTabChangedListener: (position) {
            setState(() {
              currentPage = position;
            });
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: initialize the page variable in the initState method

Comment: Are you trying to send a parameter to another screen?

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid initializing cart since its initialized while creating Sell object, and you have to add 'this' keyword when calling your parameter.

```
 class Sell extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, int> cart;

  Sell({@required this.cart}); 
  @override
  _SellState createState() => _SellState();
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations to it so other users can easily understand it.

Comment: Thanks @johannchopin I added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need pass map again to SellState like below

```
class Sell extends StatefulWidget {
  Map<String, int> cart = {};

  Sell({@required cart}); 
  @override
  _SellState createState() => _SellState(cart);
}
```

and intilise in SellState like

```
class SellState extends State<Sell> {
  Map<String, int> cart = {};

  SellState(this.cart); 

  @override
  _SellState createState() => _SellState(cart);
}
```

or you can use directly by calling

```
widget.cart
```

in SellState class